# Hardware requirments to run blender the best

Tags: hardware

I am using blender to make a simple mold.  I will not do gaming or animation just make the mold.  Notice my old lap top of 5 years has an issue with the graphics a little and I think processing.  I am getting a new computer need hardware specifications run Blender.  I want this to be a window base environment.   Most likely have get from dell where you make your own computer
on line.

I know blender can do a lot more then I require from it.  I am using probably only 10 percent of what it was intended for.  I will be sending the mold file to a 3d printer.  Is there anything I should think about when sending the mold file to the 3d printer?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to bse. Unfortunately [questions about hardware are considered off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6)  and as such will be closed as off-topic for bse.  Doesn't stop suggestions in comments.  Can't go much wrong with a dell. with a high end Nvidia gpu.  and IMHO ditch windows for a linux flavour.

Comment: If you are just going to use Blender for a very small period of time do not spend any money on hardware. You don't need a super powerful computer. SpecI ally if your goal is not to be rendered as an image. If your computer is not powerful enough to run the latest version of blender, then use an older version that runs smoothly on your existing hardware.

Comment: find a version that is as old as your computer. https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/

Comment: If you are not doing any rendering any computer will likely suffice, Blender is surprisingly lightweight and forgiving. If you get a chance and it doesn't cost too much extra, a dedicated graphics card will certainly help. Preferable NVidia or AMD. As it stands this question is offtopic here try https://blenderartists.org instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware

Comment: Thank you  we are going to upgrade need to anyhow.  Sorry no one can talk about hardware.  I think blender would cut back on user issues with the program if at least a simple out line of hardware generic hardware was given especially if blender wants to attract new users.  Nothing worse then a good program (Blender)not functioning properly because the hardware to run it is not sufficient.  New user immediately jump to conclusion and it is always the programming.
Thank you for you time

Comment: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

You can see benchmark results that people made

http://download.blender.org/institute/benchmark/latest_snapshot.html

It depends on your budget